# Why does my app always open with a memory warning, if there is almost no code for the first view?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, storyboard, nib, uistoryboard

I recently have been getting memory warning messages when I load my app on my iPhone.  I believe it has something to do with the storyboard that I recently switched over to from the classic .xib files.  The app has been running a lot slower since and I don't get why.  I got rid of a ton of my code that I was using for loading views, making tables, etc., so I would think that my app would run a lot faster now than it did before.  My mainViewController (which is giving me the most problems), only has the default code in it!  Is there a reason for this to be happening?  Was the code running faster than storyboard or something?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

Profile using Instruments to understand your app's execution -- CPU time (slow) and Allocations (memory consumption).